# If "Temperature" of a thing is literally it's average kinetic energy then why doesn't a blowing fan increase a gas's "Temperature"?

Tags: temperature

I have learnt that temperature is literally measure of KE. But I don't see a fan which increase gas's temperature. I was wondering, why?

Comment: Try to learn more details. What part of KE is relevant for temperature?

Comment: Why do you assume, a blowing fan does not increase a gas's temperature?

Comment: Because I don't see increase in temperature in daily life, practically.

Comment: I think your question concerns the blades of the fan.  But think about this:  a fan has a motor.  If you put your hand on the motor you will say that the motor is warm.   Why don't you see an increase in air temperature from that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does wind raise air temperature?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/270926/)

Comment: Accelerating a gas uniformly, i.e., all particles equally, is not *heating* but *doing work*.

Comment: The canonical duplicate is https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/96327/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A moving fan does increase the temperature of air in the room. This is because, the moving fan increases the average kinetic energy of gas molecules in the room. 
Assuming 3 degrees of freedom of gases in the room, KE = $3kT/2$, where k is the Boltzmann constant [$1.38 * 10^{-23} J/K$]. The fact is that the fan does not impart enough KE for the change in temperature to be noticeable.

Answer (score 1):

Temperature is *not* a measure of kinetic energy, or literally its average. Temperature is a measure of how much more "ordered" a system becomes when it loses energy, how much *entropy* it loses.<sup>1</sup> 
Or put another way, how easy it to spontaneously transfer energy between two systems while increasing *total* disorder (entropy).

A system with high temperature can give off much energy and become only a little more ordered. 
This concept comes from (i) energy can flow spontaneously between systems, i.e., heat can be transferred (ii) the second law of thermodynamics: the entropy must always increase.

So one introduces the quantity $\beta = \frac{dS}{dU}$, the change in entropy per change in energy. Since energy is conserved, $dU_A = -dU_B$ for two systems in thermal contact. The second law allows the energy transfer from A to B if and only iff $\beta_A \le \beta_B$. We then take $T = 1/\beta$ so we get the usual scale that heat flows from *higher* to *lower* temperatures.

Anyway, with that concept of temperature we see that it is not the average kinetic energy that matters but the distribution of it. If we accelerate a container of some gas, the relative distribution of velocities does not change, so the temperature is not different. [In fancy speech: temperature is Galilei invariant.]

Another way of stating this is that uniformly accelerating a gas, i.e., all molecules in it equally, is not *heating* it, but *doing work* on it.

Of course, in practice, there will be collisions with, say, the container walls. These are not uniform, so there will be heat transfer and the temperature changes. In fact, if you have a fluid -- gas or liquid -- and different parts of the fluid have different *average* velocities, collisions between those parts have the same effect, driving the whole fluid to have the same *average* velocity. (This is called *viscosity*, sometimes described as internal friction.) If you stir a cup of coffee, it will eventually come to rest. .

So the answer to your question, to summarize, is that a fan creates some heat, but only because anything that adds energy to a system will eventually create some heat beacuse of the second law. It is not due to increasing the average kinetic energy, because *temperature is not a measure of average kinetic energy*.

---

<sup>1</sup> It's not entirely accurate to equate disorder and entropy, the former isn't a technical term. For a given volume, [the maximum entropy system is a black hole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bekenstein_bound) which arguably is [extremely ordered](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No-hair_theorem). It is perhaps more informative to think of entropy as the negative of *information*: a black hole gives off the *least* possible information about its interior.